# Can not embed play MP3 sound files in Flash Builder 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I am currently making a Flash Builder Project using Actionscript 3.  I have come unstuck trying to embed and play MP3 sounds.  I know that the MP3 file is loading as i have traces the bytes loaded, i have also traced the function which plays the MP3.

```
import flash.media.Sound;

public class Sounds
{
    [Embed (source="bin/resources/Bounce1.mp3" )]
    private var bounce_01:Class;
    private var bounce_01_mp3:Sound

    public function Sounds()
    {
        bounce_01_mp3 = new bounce_01();
    }

    public function play():void {
        trace("play Sound");
        bounce_01_mp3.play();
    }
}
```

I call this code like so:

```
var sound_obj:Sounds = new Sounds();
sound_obj.play();
```

This is really bugging me, please can some one tell me why this does not play the sound?

Regards,

-Ben

Answer (score 0):

If you embed the sound as follows:

```
package assets.sounds
{
    import flash.media.Sound;

    [Embed (source="assets/embedded/audio/theme1.mp3")]
    public class StartScreenSound extends Sound
    {
        public function StartScreenSound()
        {
            super();
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can just call `new StartScreenSound().play();` wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. Have you tried embedding another mp3 file?

I noticed that some mp3 files on our projects hang the mxml compiler when embedded. I've posted a bug report but it hasn't been looked at yet: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29391

It seems that specific mp3 files can cause strange things in the MP3 Transcoder.

Answer (score 0):

Ben, I have spent hours messing with what I think is the same issue.  EXCEPT: My sounds were definitely playing.  If I took a sound with no blank space at the beginning and did a .Play(0,100), I would hear a very short snippet (.2 of a second maybe?) play 100 times

I had originally got a bunch of .wavs from our sound guy, and I used Switch Sound File Converter to turn them into Mp3s.  However, I just had him re-convert them for me on his machine, and somehow they are all playing fine now.  Not sure what he used but you might try modifying/converting the files themselves.